# Asynchronous OWIN pipeline

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, owin

I'm using ASP.NET 5 (core) and the OWIN pipeline. I can see many examples of how to output a response, ie:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/11/11/writing-owin-middleware.aspx

However, if you take the following:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(context =>
        {
            MvcHandler mvcHandler = new MvcHandler();
            return mvcHandler.ProcessRequest(context);
        });
    }
}

public class MvcHandler
{
    public Task ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => ProcessRequestInternal(context));
    }

    private void ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

If the above code is executed, because ProcessRequestInternal isn't asynchronous, will the requests still be responded to asynchronously or will the requests be responded to one after the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WriteAsync` is asynchronous, and is called in a non-async context. This will orphan the returned task.

You can either return the task, or wait for it.

```
private Task ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context)
{
    return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world!");
}
```

or

```
private void ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world!").Wait();
}
```

Better would be to propagate the async context:

```
private async Task ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context)
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world!");
}
```